# How to use the stomp module to send and receive a queue?

Tags: 7

Hello everyone,

I downloaded the stomp module for drupal and I just can't find any tutorial on how to use it.

I'd like to send and receive queues to and from activemq. I've an MQConsumer.php class and an MQProducer.Php class which use the fusesource stomp library and I'd like to integrate it to drupal.

I mean I've installed the module and there's like no feedback from the system. Like no UI.

Can anyone tell me how it works? I'd like to test and extend it's functionality. Thanks

Comment: this question is far too broad in scope.  we're not really equipped here to answer such a big thing, you need to break this down in to smaller more specific questions.

Comment: I just want to know how the stomp module works. It's supposed to send and receive queues to and from activeMQ. What are the steps to reproduce to send and receive a queue?

Comment: Did you read the README file about configuring STOMP as the `queue` to use in Drupal? http://cgit.drupalcode.org/stomp/tree/README.txt

Comment: I understand what you're asking,  it's just too broad a question.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Producing tutorials/documentation isn't what we're set up for (Q+A needs more specific content), but it looks like everything you need to know is in the readme file anyway. If you find that doesn't help, please feel free to ask a new, more specific question, with details of what you're doing and what's going wrong. Many thanks

Comment: I was too hasty - it's not often that an answer changes the context of the question, but I think that's happened here. Seems a perfectly reasonable and not-too-broad question now, re-opened

Comment: Cool.  Can I  ask a stupid question? why was it too broad? I'm really lost.

Comment: My opinion is your asking "how do I use stomp?". If you don't know what a Queue is, do research. Drupal has its own Queue system -- by default it provides no UI for simple queues. Drupal allows custom queue implementations. Stomp is one. Using a queue with the Drupal API is no different from any queue in any web app framework -- because a queue is a queue. This is simply not the place to ask for beginner tutorials on a technology ... be `specific` and have narrow problems, ideally with code samples. For example `This code is not processing a Stomp queue item, i get X error in PHP`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal supports its own Queue interface out the box. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.queue.inc/group/queue/7  The stomp module when configured simply moves the queue infrastructure out of Drupal and into a 3rd party system.

See the readme on this integration settings http://cgit.drupalcode.org/stomp/tree/README.txt